# Array not being assigned char after certain number of loops

Tags: c, arrays, infix-notation

I am in the process of writing an infix to postfix function. After it loops through a couple of times(8 or 9th loop), my postfix array won't accept any more characters(it's set for 100).

```
void convertToPost(char infix[], char postfix[])
{
    StackNode *pMem=NULL;
    int i=-1,j=0, priority=0,priorityStack=0,operandCounter=0;
    push(&pMem,'(');


    infix[strlen(infix)]=')';

    printf("%s\n",infix);

    for(j=0;j<strlen(infix);j++)
    {
        putchar('\n');
        printf("infix[%d]: %s\n",j,infix);
        printf("postfix[%d]: %s\n",j,postfix);
        putchar('\n');

        if(infix[j] <= 57 && infix[j] >= 48)
        {
            i++;
            postfix[i]=infix[j]; // not assigning value 8 to postfix
            i++;
            postfix[i] = ' ';    

        }
        else if(infix[j] == '(')
        {
            push(&pMem,infix[j]);
            //pop(&pMem);
        }
        else if(infix[j] == ')')
        {
            while(pMem->pNext != NULL)
            {
                if(pMem->pString == '(')
                {
                    pop(&pMem);
                }
                else
                {
                    postfix[i]= ' ';
                    i++;
                    postfix[i] = pMem->pString;
                    i++;
                    pop(&pMem);
                }// figure out how to take char from top of stack and put in postfix something pop()
                //push(&pMem,'(');
            }
            push(&pMem,'(');
            //pop(&pMem);
        }
        else if(infix[j] == '+' || infix[j] == '-' || infix[j] == '^' || infix[j] == '*' || infix[j] == '/' || infix[j] == '%')
        {
            //i--;
            if(operandCounter==0)
            {
                push(&pMem,infix[j]);
                operandCounter++;
            }
            else
            {
                priority=Precedence(infix[j]);
                priorityStack=Precedence(pMem->pString);//pString is empty
                if(priority >= priorityStack)
                {
                    if(pMem->pString != '(')
                    {
                        i++;
                        postfix[i]=pMem->pString;
                        i++;
                        postfix[i]=' ';
                        pop(&pMem);
                        push(&pMem,infix[j]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        push(&pMem,infix[j]);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

This is the sample equation that I am using: 9*(5-4)+2/6
Its output should be: (9 5 4 - * 2 6 / +)

I put a comment where the problem occurs first. It continues throughout after it reaches that point. For example when I run the code it returns: 9 5 4 - *

But gives no error codes or anything.

If you would like some of the other functions (i.e priority, push, pop) feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

inside the `for loop()`,  `strlen(infix)` value is undefined. Because you are replacing the terminating NULL character in the string.`infix[strlen(infix)]=')';` Which causes `strlen()` to return undefined value.

so change

```
 infix[strlen(infix)]=')';
```

to

```
 int len = strlen(infix);
 infix[len]=')';
 infix[len+1] = '\0';
```

Also make sure you have sufficient memory allocated for the array so the `len+1` index in the array will not be out of bounds access.